# Mark all rows as 1 when condition occurs

Tags: sql

I am trying get the records of users sending an email and the first record of someone opening the email, but then ignore all following records of the user sending an email or someone opening it.

to do this i I have been trying to use a case when with a count over, like:

```
select user_id, occurred_at, action, case when action = 'email_open' then count(*) over (partition by user_id ) else 0 end as sample from tutorial.playbook_emails
```

but that just counts total instances of the email being opened on the 'action' = 'email_opened'

is there a way anyone else knows how to do this. Image for example.

[image]

Comment: just select ```MIN``` date yeah?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a `not exists`

```
select *
from
   tutorial.playbook_emails as pe
where not exists
(
   select 1
   from
      tutorial.playbook_emails as pe2
   where
      pe2.user_id = pe.user_id and
      pe2.action = 'email_open'
      pe2.occurred_at < pe.occurred_at
)
```